# why alarm not triggering daily for specific time on every android version's devices?

Tags: java, android, calendar, alarmmanager, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using alarm Manager class.i am setting alarm for specific duration wise .like weekly or monthly so, if i want to set for monthly then i took one loop for 30 days and each Execution of loop,I am creating new alarm and set as per day*loop Number.

Problem of code is it occurs first time if mobile is not in stand by.otherwise alarm not occurring. please help.

My code as per below.

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= remdays; i++) {
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, i);
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, i, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);//
           // alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                //alarmMgr.setAlarmClock(new AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent),alarmIntent);
                alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
            } else {
                alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmIntent);
            }
  }
```

Comment: It was a choice, probably to save battery life, to accept a small delay in alarms. But not triggered at all .. can you give more details on the devices it works or not ?

Comment: do you know any other way to generate notification on specific time for a month?

Comment: Well, I would create the alarm daily, not for the all month.

Comment: mean  is one alarm triggered after generate alarm for 24 hour ?